# Provider not displaying updated state in another screen

Tags: android, flutter, dart

so im using provider and change notifier, the problem is when i change the state and notifiy listeners in the same file the user interface is updated, but when i try to access the same data from the model in another screen it still keeps the original or first version and not the updated version, the class in the other file is even using change notifier provider and a consumer just as the file with the modal class inside but is not changing the value, its only keeping the initial value, the second file only has changenotifierprovider and consumer, but it only displays the initial not the updated but the first file with the model class, and change notifier function is displaying the updated version in its widgets

this is the part of my first where i created my changenotifier, theres more but it was long so i just added this part, but all widgets here display the updated state

```
class MyModel with ChangeNotifier{



   String datesChosen = "Click here";
   String checkin;
   String checkout;
   String email;
   String name;
   String roomtype = "Click here";
   String phonenumber;
   String hotelname;



   void updateData1 (data){



           datesChosen = data;
           print(datesChosen);

           notifyListeners();





   }

    void updateData2 (data){



           roomtype = data;
           print(roomtype);

           notifyListeners();





   }
```

And this is my second screen, which only displays the intial states even after they are updated in the frst screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hotel_search/common/theme.dart';
import 'package:hotel_search/sliding_bottom_sheet_content.dart';
import 'package:hotel_search/home_page.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';



class BookScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BookScreenState createState() => _BookScreenState();
}




class _BookScreenState extends State<BookScreen> {

  




  @override
  void initState() {

    
    super.initState();
    
    /*Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000)).then((v) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    });*/
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeData = HotelConceptThemeProvider.get();
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<MyModel>(   
  
  
  create: (context) => MyModel(),
  child: MaterialApp( 
    
    
    
    
    home:Scaffold(

       backgroundColor: Colors.grey[50],
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
    onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
  ),
  
  
   elevation: 0,
        titleSpacing: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(' ' ,style: TextStyle( 
    color: Colors.black,
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
    fontSize: 20,
  ))
  
  )
  
  ,
      body:   SingleChildScrollView(

            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              ),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center, 
                children: <Widget>[
                      
                           SizedBox(height: 40,),
                      Container( 
            
     
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 100,height: 100, 
                child:Image.asset(
              "assets/images/brand.png", 
              width: 0,
              height:0,  
              fit: BoxFit.cover,)),

                     Divider(
                  height: 25,
                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                ),

                    Container( 
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:20,top:20, bottom: 20),
                 
                   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 
                           child:Text('Review \nYour Booking' ,style: TextStyle( 
    color: Colors.black, 
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
    fontSize: 30,
  ))
                    ),
                     Divider(
                  height: 25,
                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                ),



                    Container(  
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:20,top:20),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,

                      child:Text("HOTEL NAME" ,style: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
  ))
             
                


                    ),

                    Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                       Consumer<MyModel>( 
                    
                    builder: (context, myModel, children){
                    
                     return

                    Container( 
                      height: 100,
                  child: Column(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[


                    
                    Container(  
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:20,top:5),
                      width: 200,

                      child:Text(myModel.datesChosen.toString() ,style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 13,
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
  ))
             
                


                    ),

                    
                    Container(  
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:20,top:5),
                      width: 200,

                      child:Text(myModel.roomtype.toString(), style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 13,
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
  )),
  
             
                


                    )
                    ,

                       Container(  
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:20,top:5),
                      width: 200,

                      child:Text("CHECK IN AND OUT TIME" ,style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 13,
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
  ))),
  
                       Container(  
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:20,top:5),
                      width: 200,

                      child:Text("TYPE OF ROOM CHOSEN" ,style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: 13,
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
  )))

                    ] 
                    
                    ) 
                    
                    
                    );}),
      Spacer(),


          Container(
               

                       margin: EdgeInsets.only(right:20),

                                 
                            width: 150 ,
                            height:120,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("img/card.jpg"), fit: BoxFit.cover),
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),  boxShadow: [
      BoxShadow(
        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
        spreadRadius: 2,
        blurRadius: 5,
        offset: Offset(0, 3),  // changes position of shadow
      )
                ])
    
         


                    )



 ]
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 60),

                    Divider(
                      
                  height: 25,
                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                ),
                
                 SizedBox(height:20),

                Container( 
                  color:  Color(0xff008d4b),
                  height: 60,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width -50,
                child:FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {
    /*...*/
  },
  child: Text(
    "Book Now", style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
    fontSize: 20,
  ),
  ),
),
                )


                    

                 
       


              
              ]
              
              ),



            )
            )
                    )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64102906/9185411) at one of my more detailed answers about using the Provider. I think what you're missing is wrapping the application with a `Provider Widget` and calling `setState(() {});` when you make those changes.

P.S. Please use `Ctrl + Alt + L` inside the editor to indent the code properly before asking a question. What you posted is barely readable. Also, you might wanna consider splitting up your code into multiple files and not just create the whole app in main.dart. You know... just some organizing here and there.

Comment: do you mean wrappng the app in main.dart or the actual file i want to use the data, because in the actual file i  returned ChangeNotifierProvider<MyModel>

Comment: Yeah, wrap the app in main.dart with MultiProvider. Check the link I have in my answer for more details

Comment: P.S. Please indent your code and add the readable version in the initial question. You can edit your post and paste the new code in